# Plotly title is missing when combining 2 figures

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I was able to see my title when I use fig1.show() but whenever I combine it with another plot, the title goes missing. Appreciate if anyone has a solution for this.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig1 = px.scatter(df, x='DateTime', y=["Variable"], title = 'Moving Average for Variable',color=y_colors)

fig2 = px.line(df x='DateTime', y=["SMA_3"])
fig2.update_traces(line=dict(color="Green"))
    
fig3 = go.Figure(data=fig1.data + fig2.data)
fig3.show
```

Answer (score 1):

You're plotting fig3, and your title is in fig1. Here's a suggestion to rework this so that you can update traces with same formatting at the same time and apply changes to the figure globally. Adding more traces to the figure is easier as well, in my opinion.

```
fig = go.Figure()

trace1 = go.scatter(x=df['DateTime'], y=df["Variable"], color=y_colors)
trace2 = go.line(x=df['DateTime'] y=df["SMA_3"], color='Green') 

fig.add_trace(trace1)
fig.add_trace(trace2)

fig.update(layout_xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.update_layout(
title = 'Moving Average for Variable',
xaxis_title="My `enter code here`X axis",
yaxis_title="My Y axis")
fig.show()
```

I don't have your data, so can't test it. But this is how I setup all my plotly charting

Comment: Thank you. I just found out that I could do it in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I can do it in a single statement

fig3.update_layout(title='Moving Average ')